# Single Value Listener happening more than once

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a simple multiplayer game for my app, and the game play is super simple. Each player has to press 'ready' and then the game starts.

Once both players are ready, gameStarted is set to true and the gameplay (which is not controlled by the players at all) is supposed to happen. This works, but the problem is it happens more than once on a loop. This is the value event listener I have in place.

```
games.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        HomePage.getCurrentGameID(new HomePage.CallbackID() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String currentGameID) {
                if (dataSnapshot.child(currentGameID).child("player1").child("ready").getValue().equals(true)
                        && dataSnapshot.child(currentGameID).child("player2").child("ready").getValue().equals(true)) {
                    counter.run();
                }

                if (dataSnapshot.child(currentGameID).child("gameStarted").getValue().equals(true) &&
                        dataSnapshot.child(currentGameID).child("horT").getValue(Integer.class).equals(1)) {
                    headsOrTails.setText("Heads");
                    Log.i("FlipCoin", ";;happened");
                    flipHeads();
                    getResults();
                    endGame();
                } else if (dataSnapshot.child(currentGameID).child("gameStarted").getValue().equals(true) &&
                        dataSnapshot.child(currentGameID).child("horT").getValue(Integer.class).equals(2)) {
                    headsOrTails.setText("Tails");
                    Log.i("FlipCoin", ";;happened");
                    flipTails();
                    getResults();
                    endGame();
                }
```

Here is my getResults() method. I am putting it here to show that I have another value event listener being called from my `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` that I have shown above

```
private void getResults() {
    games.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            HomePage.getCurrentGameID(new HomePage.CallbackID() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(final String currentGameID) {
                    final String horT1 = dataSnapshot.child(currentGameID).child("player1").child("horT").getValue().toString();
                    final String horT2 = dataSnapshot.child(currentGameID).child("player2").child("horT").getValue().toString();
                    final double wager = Double.parseDouble(dataSnapshot.child(currentGameID).child("wager").getValue().toString());
                    HomePage.getUserPosition(new HomePage.CallbackPosition() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(int position) {
                            if(position == 1) {
                                if(horT1.equals("Heads") && dataSnapshot.child(currentGameID).child("horT").getValue(Integer.class).equals(1)
                                        || horT1.equals("Tails") && dataSnapshot.child(currentGameID).child("horT").getValue(Integer.class).equals(2)) {
                                    getWinner(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid(), wager);
                                } else {
                                    getLoser(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid(), wager);
                                }
                            }
                            if(position == 2) {
                                if(horT2.equals("Heads") && dataSnapshot.child(currentGameID).child("horT").getValue(Integer.class).equals(1)
                                        || horT2.equals("Tails") && dataSnapshot.child(currentGameID).child("horT").getValue(Integer.class).equals(2)) {
                                    getWinner(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid(), wager);
                                } else {
                                    getLoser(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid(), wager);
                                }
                            }

                            if(dataSnapshot.child(currentGameID).child("gameFinished").getValue().equals(true)) {
                                //games.child(currentGameID).removeValue();
                            }
                            endGame();
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
            }
        });
```

I thought that setting it as a Single value event listener would make it only happen once, but I have a log in there that when I run the game, is called on a loop.

How can I make this event just happen one time?

Comment: Each callback registered with `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` will run at most once. I you see multiple calls to this `onDataChange`, it means that you're registering it multiple times. To find quick proof of that, add a log statement just before the call to `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` like `Log.i("FlipCoin", "Adding listener for single value event");`

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for the help. I added the log before the listener and found that it is called a BUNCH of times. Every time anything in my database changes it is called. I have a lot of `currentGameID` callbacks throughout my class, would this be a potential reason for this issue? Is this listener being called every time the `currentGameID` callback is used anywhere in the class? I am not too sure on how to go about fixing this problem

Comment: Since you didn't show where you call the code you shared, I can't help there. But if you see that `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` is being called multiple times, that explains why `onDataChange` is also called multiple times. If you only want one call to this `onDataChange`, you should only call `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` once.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen So, I have different instances of `addListenerforSingleValueEvent` in my class, as well as different instances of `addValueEventListener`. Are these all not independent of each other? If one of my value  event listeners calls a method with another event listener, will both event listeners be called again? (I am also not sure if `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` and `addValueEventListener` relate to each other in this situation) I have added some additional code to the bottom of my original post so you can see what I am talking about (I will post it in a second)

Comment: Each listener that you register will get called for whatever you register it on. The Firebase SDK does not dedupe your listeners (that would be a pretty bad experience), although it does dedupe data requests under the hood.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks for all the info Puff. I am experimenting on how I can solve the issue using the info you gave me. If I have any further questions I'll make a detailed post.

Comment: The `games.addValueEventListener(` seems unexpected. Are you sure that shouldn't be `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`? Both technically are completely valid, but since you use a `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` in the method that calls `getResults`, I'd expect `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` in there too.